# Message passing between multiple processes each with many threads in c

Tags: c, multithreading, ipc

I have an setup with multiple (roughly 32) processes each with 2 threads. I would like to send a message from thread 0 of process A to thread 1 of process B. So, should the message be sent specifically to the thread id or to the process id. If the message is sent to the process, by default which thread will service the message?

Comment: What kind of message?

Comment: Provide info about operating system (Linux, Windows) and kind of IPC mechanism used (pipe, socket, etc.)

Comment: I am using Linux and would like to use Fifos to pass the messages. While I am aware of the structure of it, I wonder which thread (out of the two) will service the message.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways possible. Just search for [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). For example, you could use [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory), synchronized by a set of [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).